# Keyboard shortcut for horizontal rule in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to insert a horizontal rule (horizontal line across the page) in a Google Doc?

I tried looking on the Google Docs [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cpc-shortcuts) (for PC) webpage, but they didn't list one for horizontal rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Horizontal Line Keyboard Shortcut

- `Win`     <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then press <kbd>r</kbd>
- `Mac`     <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> then press <kbd>r</kbd>

---

##### Why?

- `Win`     <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
  `Mac`     <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
  Opens the "**I**nsert" menu
- <kbd>r</kbd> selects the "Ho**R**izontal line" option from the "**I**nsert" menu

---

##### How can I find other shortcuts?

Using the same approach, you can open other menus and note what letter is underlined for each option in the list. Note that menu options only include underlined letters if you open the menu from a keyboard shortcut. If you open a menu using your mouse, the underlines are absent.

**Menu Shortcuts**
                                `Win`                  `Mac`

- `File`            <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>         <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
- `Edit`            <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>        <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>
- `View`            <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>        <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- `Insert`        <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>         <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- `Format`        <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>        <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>
- `Tools`          <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>         <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
- `Extensions` <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>        <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>
- `Help`            <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>        <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

**See:** Keyboard shortcuts for Google Docs https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738

---

##### Troubleshooting

If the keyboard shortcuts do not work, check that you have your insertion point in the document (click in the page), and also insure you don't have another chrome extension (or program) interfering.